# Problema al referenciar una relación y mostrar resultado

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Os comento lo que tengo

MIGRACIÓN USERS

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
             $table->enum('tipo',['miembro','administrador'])->default('miembro');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password',60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

MIGRACIÓN IPMODELO

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateIpmodelosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ipmodelos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('ip');
           $table->timestamps();

             $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();    
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('ipmodelos');
    }
}
```

MODELO USERS

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable {
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

     protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','tipo',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];



    public function articulos()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\modelos\articulo');
    }

    public function ips()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\modelos\ipmodelo','user_id','id');
    }

   }
```

MODELO IPMODELO

```
namespace App\modelos;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ipmodelo extends Model
{
      protected $table = 'ipmodelos';

    protected  $fillable = array('ip','user_id');

    public function usuario()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

VISTA

```
      <h2>TABLA USUARIOS</h2>
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
            <th>Ip</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>

                <th>Eliminar</th>
            <th>Editar</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($usuarios as $usuarioValor)

            <tr>
                <th>{{$usuarioValor->id}}</th>
            <th>{{$usuarioValor->ips->ip}}</th>
                <th>{{$usuarioValor->name}}</th>
                <th>
                        @if($usuarioValor->tipo == 'administrador')
                            <span class="label label-danger">{{$usuarioValor->tipo}}</span>
                        @else
                            <span class="label label-primary">{{$usuarioValor->tipo}}</span>
                        @endif
                </th>


                <th>
                    {!! Form::open(array('route'=>array('usuarios.destroy',$usuarioValor->id), 'method'=>'DELETE','id'=>'eliminaPorUrl')) !!}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('seguro que deseas eliminar este registro')"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></button>
               {!! Form::close() !!}


                     </th>
               <th>

                   {!! Form::open(array('route'=>array('usuarios.edit',$usuarioValor->id), 'method'=>'GET','id'=>'eliminaPorUrl')) !!}
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" ><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button> 
              {!! Form::close() !!}
               </th>
                {{--@else
                <th></th>
                @endif--}}
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p>{{$usuarios->render()}}</p>
    </div>
```

Estoy intentando mostrar la ip del usuario pero no lo consigo. Las relaciones están hechas bien por que usando Tinker me muestra bien los resultados, de hecho hago un `dd` de `$usuarioValor->ips` y me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si intento acceder así `$usuarioValor->ips->ip`, me surge este error

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$ip

llevo un rato probando y no consigo entender el porqué.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tus migraciones, hay una relación de one-to-many entre el usuario y la ip, por lo cual asumiría que un usuario puede tener múltiples ip.

En ese orden de ideas, vemos en el resultado de tu `dd` que hay una colección (array) de elementos, en este caso de ips (así sea una sola como tal en lo que vemos), por lo cual necesitarias ejecutar un `foreach` o similar para obtener el valor deseado de la relación, o utilizar algo menos recomendado como referenciar directamente el primer elemento de la colección, algo así: `$usuarioValor->ips[0]->ip`.

La solución ideal depende del diseño de tu aplicación:

- Si necesitas o no una relación oneToMany, para determinar si la cambias a oneToOne.
- Si definitivamente debes utilizar una relación oneToMany, entonces debes llamar a las ips con un iterador o referenciar directamente la que necesites de dicha colección.

Comment: En la vista que puse, habia un foreach iterando $usuarioValor->ips->ip y aun asi no funcionaba. Probando $usuarioValor->ips[0]->ip, funciona perfectamente, pero me gustaria saber por que no funciona con el foreach que puse anteriormente

Comment: Estás iterando los usuarios `$usuarios` y no las ips, son dos cosas distintas: `$usuarioValor->ips`, aunque depende si necesitas mantener los dos foreach, uno dentro del otro claramente.

Comment: Ok, ahora si que lo entiendo, ayer estuve demasiado tiempo programando y ya no veia nada, no obstante aun sigo peleandome con el tema relaciones en laravel. Al final quedo solucionado asi
 @foreach($usuarioValor->ips as $ipsdinamicas)
                <th>{{$ipsdinamicas->ip}</th>
  @endforeach
Pues nada muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha servido mucho.